# Fields missing from folder content types

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, content-type, provisioning, schema

I have several content types based on Folder with a couple of fields.

Some of them are experiencing some strange behavior.

The fields are there, and the data is being saved, because I can see them on the list and I can add them to the view fields, but I cannot see them in the display, edit or new forms.

I have compared the schema from a working CT and a non working CT and the difference is the part below.

The properties `ShowInDisplayForm` and so on are set to `True` on all areas.

```
<XmlDocuments>
<XmlDocument NamespaceURI="Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.ContentTypeSync">
<SharedContentType xmlns="Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.ContentTypeSync" SourceId="de887f88-4a24-49db-a549-4c3cbb517053"ContentTypeId="0x012000C4E4F4EFD38B4D22A27980EC6169922F00041800E9838240F28E71F34D72B255C8" PreviousValue="false"/>
</XmlDocument>
<XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms">
<FormTemplates xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms">
<Display>ListForm</Display>
<Edit>ListForm</Edit>
<New>ListForm</New>
</FormTemplates>
</XmlDocument>
</XmlDocuments>
```

In my schema I just have the content type id, name and field refs. Not sure if I need anything else like the above, and I wonder why it works for some content types just not others (perhaps the others were manually added).
[image]

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Creating a new form for the library/content type shows the missing fields.

I would like to fix the underlying issue, rather than creating new forms, also because Upload.aspx is experiencing the same behavior and since I am in a position where I can delete the libraries and content types and redeploy the solution.

Comment: Can you check the content type and their fields? And also is there a way you can delete the associated info path form and create a new one just for testing?

Comment: I cannot detect anything wrong as apparently everything is working fine, with the fields appearing in the list settings, and storing data as they should. The forms are ootb forms and the fields refuse to display in either the forms (New, Display, Edit) or Upload.aspx when it is first created.

Comment: From the SharePoint Designer can you create a new form and see you are getting all fields populated. I had this issue earlier and created a new form populated all fields.

Comment: If I create a new Edit form, it appears that the missing fields appear. But I don't think this can be an acceptable workaround. This means creating 4 custom forms but hundreds of lists. I really need to figure out why it works on some cases and not in others so I can fix whenever this happens. Also, this doesn't fix Upload.aspx

Comment: Where are the names for the `FieldRef`?

Comment: @Mike just regular internal names, e.g. Company_Project_FieldName, following by their actual display names (e.g. Start Date, End Date, Contract Number, etc.)

Comment: This might be a problem with list provision with the content type. Can you update with schema.xml file

Comment: I'm saying in your screenshot you don't have the `Name` property filled in your screenshot. `Name` is a required field for the `FieldRef` tag. Can you update it?

Comment: the fields were removed for confidentiality reasons. unless there are strong reasons to disclose them, I'd rather not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a fix, although I have no idea how, or why this works, or what the hell is the `de887f88-4a24-49db-a549-4c3cbb517053` guid (appears to be the `SspId`), but I do know that this ID is the same on all environments and the CT ID is the one from the parent content type, so **adding this XML will effectively make all fields appear**, just as if the content type was manually created from the user interface...

Now if only I could understand why this works or why we need it, that'd be great! :-)

```
<XmlDocuments>
<XmlDocument NamespaceURI="Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.ContentTypeSync">
<SharedContentType xmlns="Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.ContentTypeSync" SourceId="de887f88-4a24-49db-a549-4c3cbb517053" ContentTypeId="0x012000C4E4F4EFD38B4D22A27980EC6169922F00805E034530134878AB63F79948351B4B" PreviousValue="false"/>
</XmlDocument>
<XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms">
<FormTemplates xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms">
<Display>ListForm</Display>
<Edit>ListForm</Edit>
<New>ListForm</New>
</FormTemplates>
</XmlDocument>
</XmlDocuments>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your form in InfoPath or Nintex and you will see all the fields. Display the desired fields on the form and publish.

Comment: this is ootb sharepoint forms. I don't have, or plan to have custom made forms